# Django - Celery catch(try-except block) errors - issues with freezing/hang code

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I'm using PythonDjango with Celery and Redis and I want to catch two erros:

1. The first error `OperationalError` means the server is down
2. If app.control.inspect().active() is None, the workers are down

Functionality:

1. If there is not an `OperationalError` it should check also `app.control.inspect().active()`
2. If there is an `OperationalError` it shouldn't check `app.control.inspect().active()` because Celery will hang/freeze
3. The Celery task will not work in both cases but just the Redis server down will have an exception

Code:

```
   if not error:
        try:
          send_email_task.delay(subject=subject, ..., html_content=html_content)
        except OperationalError as e:
            # do something
        if not app.control.inspect().active():
                # do something   
     else:
     ......
```

My issue, if I have an `OperationalError` the condition  `if not app.control.inspect().active()` will hang the code

If I add the code `app.control.inspect().active()` inside `try` will hang/freeze, will indefinitely check status if is an `OperationalError`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the `else` block in `try-catch`

Try:

```
if not error:    
    try:
      send_email_task.delay(subject=subject, ..., html_content=html_content)
    except OperationalError as e:
        # do something
    else:
        if not app.control.inspect().active():
            # do something   
else:
    ......
```

Comment: I'm afraid that `send_email_task.delay()` will never raise an exception in django. It will raise in `celery`...right?

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure. I have not used `celery`